# How to verify if vectors of $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ span $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have three square matrices as following:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

How can I verify if they span $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ ?

So far I have only learned the fact that if vectors span $\mathbb{R}^n$, the matrix A composing of the vectors in their column form will have n pivots

My main problem is that I am not sure how can I put them into column form as they are square matrices. I have only dealt with vectors of $n \times 1$. In these cases, it is easy for me to verify if they span a particular space.

Comment: An element of the span is a linear combination of these things (i.e. $a$ times the first plus $b$ times the second plus $c$ times the third), which will look like $\begin{pmatrix}a & c \\ c & b \end{pmatrix}$. Is everything in $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ of this form? Why or why not?

Comment: Oh okay thanks a lot! I understand now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also view it as follows: A matrix in $\Bbb R^{2\times 2}$ consists of 4 real values. This means $\Bbb R^{2\times 2}$ is basically $\Bbb R^4$, since you get an isomorphism of vector spaces via
$$
\Bbb R^{2\times 2} \to \Bbb R^4, \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} a\\b\\c\\d \end{pmatrix}.
$$
But $\Bbb R^4$ has dimension 4 (for example $\{(1,0,0,0)^T, (0,1,0,0)^T, (0,0,1,0)^T , (0,0,0,1)^T\}$ is a basis), so $\Bbb R^{2\times 2}$ must have dimension 4, thus $3$ elements can't span the whole vector space.

Answer (score 3):

How would you get $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}$?